# Visual Studio 2017 "The application is in break mode visual studio 2017"

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I was working on a C# console app and it was working fine until yesterday. When I am trying to run the same console application, it is not allowing me to debug, saying error as "The application is in break mode.  Your app has entered a break state, but no code is currently executing that is supported by the selected debug engine (e.g. only native runtime code is executing)."

Did anyone faced a similar issue and resolved it earlier.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this issue in a console app that was using a custom config section. See [configSections element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/configsections-element-for-configuration): *If this element is in a configuration file, it must be the first child element of the configuration element*.

Making the configSections element the first child of the configuration element resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

(To be filed under "This worked for me, maybe it will work for you.")

Rename your Main function to MainInternal, adding a new Main that just calls through to MainInternal.

When I did this, instead of getting that "The application is in break mode" error, I got an exception I could examine at the point MainInternal was called.

Comment: Give that man a see-gar!    

This is exactly what I did and was able to view the actual exception and diagnose my problem from there.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have changed someting. I was getting such error in such situation:

```
            myfr.Navigate(new Uri("ararAbonamenty_page.xaml",
                 UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

But the page name was arAbonamenty_page.xaml, changing it caused myapplicaton to run properly.